# What do conjugacy classes of involutions like in finite simple group $E_7(q)$?

Tags: finite-groups, involutions, conjugacy-classes

Are there any refences for conjugacy classes of involutions in finite simple group $E_7(q)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $q$ odd see:

D. Gorenstein, R. Lyons and R. Solomon,The classification of the finite simple groups, Number 3,Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, vol. 40, Amer. Math. Soc., 1998 MR1490581

For $q$ even:

Aschbacher, Michael M., and Gary M. Seitz. "Involutions in Chevalley Groups over Fields of Even Order." Nagoya Mathematical Journal 63 (1976): 1-91. Web. MR0422401

Comment: Thank you very much!